# How do I know if my skins compression clothing are too tight or not tight enough?

Tags: compression

Recently, I decided to invest in some Skins as I've been doing a bit of exercise. I plan to use them for things like running, cycling and maybe soccer.

On the packet I'm right on the verge of being a S or M. I decided to buy the S citing the shop assistant's advice that they should be tight to work.

I just gave them a try on a bike ride - at first they felt really tight and weird, but after I got used to it, I think they felt okay.

The only problem was when I got home and it was a real struggle trying to take them off. Is that normal? I eventually somehow violently got them off - I'm scared though that if I have to do that every time, I may end up ripping them or stretching them out of shape.

They came off okay in the shop but maybe as they were a bit damp from my sweat, it was a little harder. Is that normal? Should I just wait till after I've cooled down a bit to take the skins off?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be fine. The compression clothing is designed to be tight, and if you can fit into it, you should be good.

As far as taking it off... I agree it can be a little weird, depending on what piece of clothing it is. I like to kind of peel it off, as opposed to the normal shrugging off I would do with normal clothes.

Honestly there's no way I can prove to you that you won't damage your clothes by taking them off, but if they're well made they should be pretty durable. And my guess is you'll develop some interesting dance moves to get them off over time :)

I have a few pairs of compression shorts and compression tops, and none of them have ripped or deformed in spite of my sometimes hilarious means of removing myself from them.